# How to stream RTMP direct from an android divice to a windows pc in the fild without any Network

Tags: stream, rtmp, dji-sdk

i would like to stream Dron video from the controler (Dji mavic air 2 with a RC-N1 controler) via RTMP direktly from the controler/my Phone to my PC wihl i am in the fields without having any internet conection or an extra Network. Is that some how possible?

Answer (score 3):

First, you still need a network. You can create a hotspot using a computer (laptop) or a device that connects to the RC-controller (phone, tablet).
Secondly, you need an RTMP server that will be located in this network. As a quick example, I can recommend [MonaServer2](https://github.com/MonaSolutions/MonaServer2), it is easy to install and run.
Thirdly, you need someone who will "listen" to the server when the stream comes to it. For example, you can use a VLC player. Launch it and specify RTMP stream as a source.

So, you start the RTMP-server, let's say it is located at 192.168.0.1:1935. On your device connected to the RC-controller, using the standard DJI-Fly application or your own app developed using Mobile SDK, select the option to start streaming, specify the address: rtmp://192.168.0.1:1935/live. Next, launch VLC-Player, select File->Open Network Stream and type rtmp://192.168.0.1:1935/live in URL field. Now you will be able to watch live-stream in your VLC window.

This is the fastest and easiest way I can recommend.

Also you can take raw h264 frames from camera, send them to decoder and do whatever you want. If you need some more info about it feel free to ask. Hope it helps!