# Is it possible to access DJI Mavic's camera video and process it realtime on the external device?

Tags: camera, dji-sdk, nvidia-jetson, raw

I want to realtime process video that captures DJI Mavic using onboard NVidia Jetson module. Is it possible to use video data in external device? How to access it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Turn on a video stream, grab it in external device (for example, via openCV), then process. Since you have cv::Mat object for each frame you can do anything. For video streaming setup you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73877474/20107815). To open video stream in opencv you should create a `Video Capture` with RTMP address as parameter.
2. Grab raw frames data from camera using DJI SDK. Now you can decode them either via SDK using your device's GPU or send raw data to your external device over TCP or whatever you like and then decode. After decoding you can process each frame in your needs. [Starting point](https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/sample-code/index.html) for this approach.

If you need more in-depth information or have any questions feel free to ask.